# View Columns not appear

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, view, model

I have a database view in SQL Server that have 54 columns on my local environment 
I have created a model for the view 
protected `$table = 'view_name';`

and called the model in my controller and everything is very well, after uploading by pushing the change on the server when I make a dd(Model) not all columns appear just 27 Columns only?

I did check the view on the database and everything is fine?

I tried to restart SQL server 
clear view cache, cache, composer auto-dump Nothing solve the problem
any ideas about what could be done?

Comment: Are you sure you do not need to do `php artisan migrate` or `php artisan migrate:fresh` ?

Comment: I have already build a migration for the view and already run it which created the view

Comment: I take your advice (Goms) and inspire me do this in a migration :

DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec("Alter View As Select * from table");

it worked fine ... any scientific explanation ...

Comment: kindly share the code of your model so that i can help you out